# Make an ajax call in observer on 'checkout_cart_product_add_after' event

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript, ajax

Need to fire an ajax call after adding a product to magento cart. looking for list of Magento Javascript Events to achieve this. any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by Javascript Events? can you give an example?

Comment: was referring to this post. 
http://alanstorm.com/magento_javascript_events
purpose is to do some js stuff and make an ajax call in observer on 'checkout_cart_product_add_after' event.

Comment: What post? I don't understand. but maybe it's just me.

Comment: edited my comment .

Comment: need to store all the info of product which is being added to the cart on another server using jquery ajax. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: It's clear now. I just don't have any ideas.

Comment: @vibhu `checkout_cart_product_add_after` is server side event (PHP). How do you want to trigger a JavaScript AJAX call from PHP? If you want you can create a curl request from PHP

Comment: @alex.ayg that is why i am also looking for any JavaScript event mechanism provided by magento.

Comment: Nope, sorry but there isn't any. Because the addToCart functionality refreshes the page, you cannot know inside JavaScript if the product had been added to cart. I still recommend you create a PHP request

Comment: yes, http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/tracking-magento-add-product-to-cart-action- it is working for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Found this post - http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/tracking-magento-add-product-to-cart-action-for-analytic-software-purpose/

It did the trick for me :)

Comment: Please describe more what you did - link only posts are discouraged.